# Unable to Select Stylesheet for New Angular Project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to get the Angular CLI working for an existing app that uses .NET Core, before upgrading the app from Angular 2 to 7. I've decided it would be best to make a new Angular project using the CLI and migrate code/components over to the new project incrementally.

I changed the name of the current Angular project, navigated out of the project directory and tried to create a new app using ng new . When I select the stylesheet I get the below error.

```
Invalid rule result: Instance of class Promise.
```

I understand that Angular 8 is available, however I have been asked to perform the upgrade to 7 instead.

```
Angular CLI: 7.2.1
Node: 10.15.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.12.1
@angular-devkit/core         7.2.1
@angular-devkit/schematics   7.2.1
@schematics/angular          7.2.1
@schematics/update           0.12.1
rxjs                         6.3.3
typescript                   3.2.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I solved my own question. I had multiple versions of Angular so things were getting confused.

Comment: If you solved your own question, you should accept your answer.

Comment: My apologies. I intended to, but I receive a message saying that I can accept my own answer in two days.